# Rails - Incorrect database entries in Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to create a form to handle the creation of addresses. I have three models, AddressInfo, Address, and Client. AddressInfo will store the type of address such as present, mailing or employer and link to a ClientID and an AddressID. This is used to prevent duplicate addresses in case someone uses their employer address as a mailing address. The problem I am having at the moment is that I can't seem to get the AddressID to link to the AddressInfo row.

This is my rails console attempt and the desired behavior:[image]

This is my output: Ignore the entries in address at the moment since those are just seed files. Addressinfo(3) is the entry I tried to add through the interface and it doesn't create a new address.
[image]
Here is my view:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :address_infos do |presinfo_form|%>
        <%= presinfo_form.fields_for :addresses do |address_form| %>
             <%= address_form.label :"Present Address" %>
             <%= address_form.text_field :street %>
        end
        <%= presinfo_form.label :"Type" %>
        <%= presinfo_form.text_field :addresstype, :value => "present" %>
    end
end
```

And the models:

```
class AddressInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :address_infos
    has_many :clients, through: :address_infos
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :address_infos
    has_many :addresses, through :address_infos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :address_infos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Client controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.address_infos.build
    @client.addresses.build
end

def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    if @client.save
        redirect_to root_url 
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end


private
    def client_params
        params.require(:client).permit(:firstname, :middlename, :lastname, 
        address_infos_attributes: [:ownorrent, :addresstype, :yearsofresidency,
        addresses_attributes: [:street, :city, :state, :zipcode]]
    )
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you create some entries through the Rails console and show us what isn't working?  Similarly, if it works in the console, show us the view where the create isn't working.

Comment: Updated main post, please let me know if you'd like anything else to be provided.

Comment: Please capture the Rails console steps you used to attempt to create instances and/or associations, explain what you expected to happen and show what happened.

Comment: Sorry, never really used rails console to add entires to the database, but I tried. If there's a better way to add in an address then please let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily need to create join table entries.  So once you create a client for instance (`c = Client.create...`), if you use the addresses association for that client to create an address (`c.addresses << Address.create...`), you should get the join table entry (`Address_info`) as well.

Comment: Ah okay, so how would I edit the row for address_info that it creates? Right now in the database it's just blank.

Comment: So you did as suggested?  What does the new address_info instance look like?  What are you trying to accomplish?